# Show the data in red in model table in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to show the data in red in model table in Swing?

Table data is correct. If, result is pass it should appear in green and result is failed then same should be in red color in model table in swing

```
    if (newResultSet.isEmpty() != true) {
        // System.out.println("final calculated summary records size : "+newResultSet.size());

        for (int indx = 0; indx < newResultSet.size(); indx++) {
            Resultset rs = (Resultset) newResultSet.get(indx);

            Object[] row = new Object[6];

            row[0] = rs.getTestCaseNumber();
            row[1] = rs.getTestExecution();
            row[2] = rs.getTestCasePass();
            row[3] = rs.getTestCaseFail();
            row[4] = rs.getTestResult();
            row[5] = rs.getTestCaseDateTime();

            //System.out.println(row[0].toString()+" "+row[2].toString()+"  "+row[3].toString());

            model.addRow(row);
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO DATA IS AVAILABLE TO DISPLAY", "Empty Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Execution Report Table");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);


    summarizeData();

    final JTable table = new JTable(model);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane);

    setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I want show the result in red and green row in ModelTable.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: where is this model object? The start of your code is incomplete

Answer (score 2):

Create a **CellRenderer** on the 4th column in the table. Your result object gets passed into its method, and in that method you can check the result, and change the label or panel background to green or red.

Your **model** object should be an implementation of the **ABstractTableModel** class.

Your renderer should look something like this :

```
public class ColorRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object color,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {

        if(table.getValueAt(row, 4).equals("fail")) {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }else {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN)
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

You need to add this renderer to ALL columns in your table.

Comment: *"Your model object should be an implementation of the ABstractTableModel class"* ... Why?

Comment: ok, not quite necessary in this case. Yes you can add a cellrenderer to a table without defining its own model. But it's nice.

Answer (score 2):

In order to effect the state of any cell in a `JTable` you need to supply a custom `TableCellRenderer`.

See [how to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details.

Now.  This is a lot of work to simply highlight a row.

Instead you might be better of taking a look [JXTable from SwingX](https://java.net/projects/swingx) which provides row highlighting

For [example](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91834162.html)

Answer (score 1):

> If, result is pass it should appear in green and result is failed then same should be in red

See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for an example that allows your to renderer an entire row a certain color based on a value in one of the columns. This approach works without creating custom renderers.